# Indexing in google play

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way of setting tags for you application in google play.
I have created an application but the only way I can view it is by searching for it package name.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

indexing takes time. you cant tag your apps. but you can provide a relevant description, promo text to the app.